# Firebase realtime database rules prevent node deletion

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My users database look like:

```
root
  users
   453453452
       name: user1
       email: email@example.com
       permissions: [1,2,3]
   457575684
       name: user2
       email: email2@example.com
       permissions: [1,2,3]
   234235346
   123245346
   436286785
   474574725
```

What I am trying to do is to allow writing to `/users`, and to a user node `/users/453453452`, but prevent deleting the users table or any user node.

What I tried:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "users": {
            ".read": false,
            ".write": "newData.exists() && newData.val() != null",
            "$user": {
                ".read": true,
                ".write": "newData.exists() && newData.val() != null",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am still able to delete any node if I send a DELETE request to `/users/453453452.json`.

Can I get some help about that please?

Edit: 
1- Adding user to database after a successful purchase, where `userID` is a hashed unique identifier of the user by their email address.

```
fetch(myAPI + "/" + userID + ".json", {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {'Accept': 'application/json, application/xml, text/plain, text/html, *.*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'},
    body: JSON.stringify({"name": userName,"email": userEmail, "order_id": orderID})
});
```

I can easily send a DELETE request with POSTMAN to `myAPI + "/" + userID + ".json"` to delete the selected record, which I am trying to avoid, or even sending an empty array to `/users` which will wipe the whole database.

Comment: That sounds unexpected. Are you authenticating your REST client in any way?

Comment: No, I am not. We're trying to make the app as easy as possible, and in our scenario we cannot ask users to login or authenticate.

Comment: Got it. I was "hoping" you were passing an OAuth token, because that could explain. Can you edit your question with an example of the exact call you do? I'm going to try and reproduce this problem, and might want to use your implementation for reference against mine.

Comment: I edited the question, I hope the edit is useful enough.

Comment: Could you find a way, Frank?

Comment: Sorry, I've been terribly busy with other things. I'll still try to get to it, but probably not today anymore.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I appreciate your kind help so much, it's a very sensitive matter to us, i'll be waiting, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce the problem [here](https://jsbin.com/gosaqut/edit?js,console). The full code I use is:

```
var url = "https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/61015647";

fetch(url+".json", {
  method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
  headers: {
    //'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(Date.now())
}).then(function(response) {
  return response.json()
}).then(function(json) { 
  console.log("Child "+json.name+" added, trying to delete with POST...");
  return fetch(url+"/"+json.name+".json", {
    method: "DELETE"
  })
}).then(function(response) {
  return response.json()
}).then(function(json) { 
  console.log(json);
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```

And the relevant rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "61015647": { 
      ".read": true, 
      "$child": { 
        ".write": "newData.exists() && newData.val() != null" 
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this code, the output is:

> null (the initial value from the on("value" listener)
>
> "Child -M44hzNISkQNvycyH63B added, trying to delete with POST..."
>
> [object Object] {
>     error: "Permission denied"
>   }
>
> [object Object] { (the next value from the on("value" listener)
>     -M44hzNISkQNvycyH63B: 1586012616166
>   }

Comment: Oh, thank you for taking time to check it, did you try to do it with PostMan? I can easily send a delete request and remove the node with PostMan.

Comment: I intentionally picked the simplest implementation I could think of, without libraries or tools, to rule out whatever those might be doing. If Postman allows you to do more, it is likely sending extra information along to authenticate. If you set up a reproduction on a similar environment as I have, I'll have a look.

Comment: Any update? If you're seeing different behavior than I showed in the jsbin, I'd love to see it in a similar implementation that I can take a look at.

Comment: Hi Frank, please bear with me a little bit more, i will come back later to comment here.